# How to build multiple Source files according to their respective headers Dependency in Makefile?

Tags: c++, unix, sed, makefile, gnu-make

I found it obscure to use make utility to generate header dependencies `makefile` for the source file and using this build the library or create executable accordingly.

1)

As suggested in the manual:

http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Prerequisites.html#Automatic-Prerequisites

I tried with the approach mentioned over there (In my case dependency files are present under obj/):

```
obj/%.d:%.cpp
    @set -e; rm -f $@; \
    g++ -MM $(CPPFLAGS) ${INC_FLAGS} $< > $@.$$$$; \
    sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@; \
    rm -f $@.$$$$
```

But this throws a shell error:

```
/bin/sh: cannot create obj/xyz.d.23030: Directory nonexistent
```

However obj directory is present, I didn't understand the use of sed command. The manual explains that it replaces any "**.obj : .cpp**" rule to ".**obj .dep : .cpp**", But How ?

2)
I also tried the approach mentioned over here :
http://mad-scientist.net/make/autodep.html

```
obj/%.o : %.c
    g++ -MMD ${CPPFLAGS} ${INC_FLAGS} -c $$<  -o $$@
    @cp obj/$*.d obj/$*.P; \
    sed -e 's/#.*//' -e 's/^[^:]*: *//' -e 's/ *\\$$//' \
        -e '/^$$/ d' -e 's/$$/ :/' < $*.d >> $*.P; \
    rm -f $*.d
```

Using this dependency file is generated but following error message is asserted:

```
"/bin/sh: cannot open obj/%.P: No such file"
sed: -e expression #2, char 4: unterminated `s' command
```

Again use of `sed` is not clear.

This becomes more obfuscate ... Here In the second approach if I don't add separate rule to create dependency files and generate them at the time of object creation, As "g++ -MP -MMD -c" creates both .o and .d. **But how .o will be compiled again using the dependency makefile which is generated in the same command ?**

I appreciate any help in resolving the errors occurred, And helping me in understanding this.
Or Please suggest some elegant approach to do the same.

**EDIT : (As suggested in the comment)
In the second approach using both -MMD and -MP it works as expected, But I can't understand how it's working. Here sed comamnd is not required, and source gets rebuild if related header is modified:**

obj/%.o : %.c
        g++ -MMD -MP ${CPPFLAGS} ${INC_FLAGS} -c $$<  -o $$@

But As described in [gcc manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc) , If I didn't interpreted it wrong -MMD used to generate the dependency(excluding system header) file and -MP used to generate empty rule for each header, But it only modifies the object rule:
i.e.,

`obj/%.o obj/%.d : %.cpp` (This is what sed is doing as mentioned in GNU make manual)

or something like,

```
obj/%.o : %.cpp (list of dependent headers for particular .cpp file)
```

What is the use of following two commands and how it works ?

a)`sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@;`

b)

```
sed -e 's/#.*//' -e 's/^[^:]*: *//' -e 's/ *\\$$//' \
                -e '/^$$/ d' -e 's/$$/ :/' < $*.d >> $*.P;
```

Comment: Try compiling directly with the `-MMD` and `-MP` options, this will generate a `.d` file for every source file.

Comment: You don't need `sed` for this for the last 10 years or so. That is a very old article, not sure if it is of any use these days.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin if sed is not used then how %.o should be translated in %.o %.d, which is actually require at the time of each source file building according to the changes in respected dependent header (or dependencies listed in generated .d makefile).

Comment: @user657267 Using -MMD and -MP both options during object file creation, did the trick, But I didn't understand How? Because this flags hels in dependencies generation, How object rule made dependent on depency makefiles as I need not to use `sed` in this approach, Please help me in understanding this.

Comment: @ronexdicapriyo I'm not sure I understand you, it works because that's exactly what those two options were designed to do.

Answer (score 2):

> However obj directory is present,

Apparently it isn't. That's the first thing you need to solve.

> I didn't understand the use of sed command. The manual explains that it replaces any **".obj : .cpp"** rule to **".obj .dep : .cpp"**, But How ?

The special make variable `$*` contains the stem that matched the pattern of the target, which will be the part of the target that matches the pattern `%`

The sed command replaces `obj/%.o:` with `obj.o obj.d:`, exactly as the Make manual says. To explain "how" you need to understand sed, but it's not a very complicated sed command.

> Using this dependency file is generated but following error message is asserted:

That make recipe has a `#` character, which means everything after it is a comment, you need to escape it with `\#`

However, if you're using GCC it's easier to just add `-MMD` to the normal recipe for generating object files, which will produce the `.d` files as a side-effect of compilation, so you don't need a separate target for the `.d` files.

Comment: If $* is "obj/%" -> suppose "obj/%.o" is invoked for xyz.cpp fle then, if I use cp $*.d $*.p it translated into cp .d .p which actually should be cp obj/xyz.d obj/xyz.p.... Can you please write the lines of cp and sed command which should be used in my case (considering .o and .p are present in the same "obj" directory). As far as sed concern I know that it can be used for find and replace stuff but here it has used many automatic variable which maks it nebulous.

Comment: Sorry, I got the description of $* slightly wrong, it contains whatever matches `%`, not `obj/%`, which is OK in the original example from the make manual because there is no `obj` sub-directory. To adapt the example to work with an `obj` sub-directory you need to to include `obj` in the sed rule ... but just use `-MMD` and don't bother. I'm not going to waste my time and your time giving you commands you don't understand to do something the compiler does automatically.

Answer (score -1):

So this is a makefile I wrote for one of my modules at university, you can try using it, when you call make it generates all the files and links all the files without needing to define anything extra in the file. There is a lot of excess stuff here, but I did this quite a while ago, but you can take things out and play around with it to see what you can remove. Hope this helps =)

```
CC=g++

WARNING_FLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -Weffc++ -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs \
-Wswitch-default -Wswitch-enum -Wunused-parameter -Wstrict-overflow=5 \
-Wfloat-equal -Wshadow -Wc++0x-compat -Wconversion -Wsign-conversion \
-Wmissing-declarations -Wstrict-null-sentinel -Woverloaded-virtual -Wsign-promo\
-Werror -pedantic
FORMATTING_FLAGS=-fno-pretty-templates -fmessage-length=80 -fdiagnostics-show-option
CFLAGS=${WARNING_FLAGS} ${FORMATTING_FLAGS} -g -std=c++0x -pipe  -frepo

LDFLAGS=
LDLIBS=-lGL -lGLEW -lglut -lGLU -lX11 -lXi -lm -lpng

TARGET=main
OBJECTS=$(addsuffix .o, $(basename $(shell ls *.C | grep -v Test)))
HEADERS=$(addsuffix .h, $(basename $(shell ls *.h | grep -v Test)))

TEST_LDFLAGS=-lboost_unit_test_framework
TEST_LDLIBS=${LDLIBS}
TEST_TARGET=test
TEST_OBJECTS=$(addsuffix .o, $(basename $(shell ls *.C | grep -v main)))

CLEAN_TARGETS=$(addsuffix .o, $(basename $(shell ls *.C))) ${TARGET} ${TEST_TARGET} *.rpo *.gch makefile.dep

all: ${OBJECTS} 
    ${CC} ${LDFLAGS} ${LDLIBS} $^ -o ${TARGET}

test: ${TEST_OBJECTS}
    ${CC} ${TEST_LDFLAGS} ${TEST_LDLIBS} $^ -o ${TEST_TARGET}

%.o:
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c ${LDFLAGS} $< -o $@

Test.o: Test.C Makefile
    ${CC} -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm ${CLEAN_TARGETS}

makefile.dep: *.[Ch]
    for i in *.C; do gcc -std=c++0x -MM "$${i}"; done > $@
include makefile.dep
```

Comment: Nah, as Jon said, there is no need for a separate dependency-generating rule. Ask your professor to update the stuff he teaches.